# Birt: hide/show navigation bar through javascript within report?

Tags: javascript, birt

There is a navigation bar in Birt report that shows the number of pages and current page etc (page1 of 22 etc) and also provide option of jumping to a specific page

My requirement is that if there is only one page in the report, hide the navigation bar and if there are multiple pages, then show the navigation bar

I have currently hidden the navigation bar permanantly from .webappsbirtwebcontentbirtpagescontrolNavigationbarFragment.jsp but now I want the navigation bar in reports that have more than one page so that  a user can jump to other pages too

Can someone please give some hint/tip on how to disable/enable the navigation bar through javascript from within the Birt report

Arif

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
var uiOptions = this.getViewer().getUIOptions();
    uiOptions.enableToolBar(false);
    this.getViewer().setUIOptions(uiOptions);
```

Here is how you would do it if you use an HTML button. Add the following script to the HTML button:

```
var toolbar = true;

this.onclick = function(event)
{ 
if (toolbar === true) { 
var uiOptions = this.getViewer().getUIOptions();
uiOptions.enableToolBar(false);
this.getViewer().setUIOptions(uiOptions);
toolbar = false;}

else
{
var uiOptions = this.getViewer().getUIOptions();
uiOptions.enableToolBar(true);
this.getViewer().setUIOptions(uiOptions);
toolbar = true;}
}
```